# UIPanGestureRecognizer to maximize and minimize a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

To minimize and maximize a UIView I am using a UIPangestureRecognizer. The code is listed below:

```
-(void) pannningMyView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture{
    CGPoint newPoint=[panGesture translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint oldPoint=self.myPanningView.frame.origin;
    CGFloat dx=newPoint.x;
    CGFloat dy=newPoint.y;
    if(dx>0){
        CGRect oldRect=self.myPanningView.frame;
        oldRect.size.width+=dx;
        oldRect.size.height+=dy;
        self.myPanningView.frame=oldRect;
    }
}
```

But, the transition is very fast, such that I move few pixels and it covers the entire screen. I am not able to figure out what correction is required to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your translations are cumulative because the `translationInView` is from the beginning of the continuous gesture, but you're you're adding the translation to the current frame, not the original frame. This is solved by checking the gesture state, and if you're at the start of the gesture then save the original frame, and then use that as the basis for future translations as the gesture proceeds.

```
-(void) panningMyView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture
{
    static CGRect originalFrame; // or you could make this a non-static class ivar

    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalFrame = self.myPanningView.frame;
    }
    else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
        if (translation.x > 0) {
            CGRect newFrame = originalFrame;
            newFrame.size.width += translation.x;
            newFrame.size.height += translation.y;
            self.myPanningView.frame = newFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I got rid of `oldPoint` because you didn't seem to be using it. I also renamed `newPoint` to `translation` because it's not a point on the screen but a measure of how much your finger has moved (or translated) on the screen. I also renamed `oldRect` to `newFrame`, because I think that more accurately captures what it is.

Essentially, I've tried to preserve the logic of your routine, but simply clarify your logic and variable names. I would have thought that you might want an additional `else if` cause, checking for ended or canceled gestures, using an animation to complete or reverse the gesture as appropriate, but I didn't tackle that as you didn't reference this in your original question.

Regardless, I hope you get the idea of what we're doing here. We're saving the original frame and applying the translation to that rather than applying it to the current frame.

---

**Update:**

In a follow up question, you asked how you might clarify the animation. You might do something like:

```
-(void) panningMyView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture
{
    static CGRect originalFrame; // or you could make this a non-static class ivar
    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];

    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalFrame = self.myPanningView.frame;
    }
    else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        if (translation.x > 0) {
            CGRect newFrame = originalFrame;
            newFrame.size.width += translation.x;
            newFrame.size.height += translation.y;
            self.myPanningView.frame = newFrame;
        }
    }
    else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
             panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
             panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        CGRect finalFrame = originalFrame;

        // if we've gone more than half way, move it all the way, 
        // otherwise return it to the original frame

        if (translation.x > (self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0))
        {
            finalFrame.size.width += self.view.frame.size.width;
            finalFrame.size.height += self.view.frame.size.height;
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                                self.myPanningView.frame = finalFrame;
                             }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: nice explanation, I messed up with the terminology. But, You made them pretty clear.

Comment: Everything is handled in stateChanged, so In ended state what kind of animation can be shown as the last frame dimension is set in stateChanged.

Comment: @andyPaul I've updated my answer with another example where I added gesture ending animation. What I'm suggesting is some logic that says "hey, if I'm more than half way across, set `finalFrame` to be the final frame size, and then animate. If not more than half way across, then animate the return of this back to the original size". Clearly, I don't know what the appropriate `finalFrame.size` value, so I made a guess, but you'll have to alter that (as well as the `if` statement as to how much `translation` qualifies for "more than half way"), but you get the idea.

Comment: Rob I got it. But, there is something else which I was trying out to show a animation by Highlighting its border , code at http://pastebin.com/BW4UYiM2...But, animation does not show up

Comment: @andyPaul Ok, it looks like you don't want to complete the user's gesture, but rather you want to make the border color blink red momentarily. That's fine, though if you're using `CALayer` properties like `borderColor`, that's not animatable. So you have to use `transitionWithView` rather than `animateWithDuration`. I'd also encourage you to try `options` value of `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` to polish the effect.